# Android Resources$NotFoundException on Gradle 3.0 or later

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

this is my first question so please be merciful.

I have an app that is dependent on the following library: https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton

The library was working fine on pre Gradle 3. Now every time I run the app I get the following log:

---

```
___
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest, PID: 2829
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest/com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest:dimen/progress_inner_size" (7f050067) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1c01 a=4 r=0x7f050067}
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java)
                      at com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton.init(ProgressButton.java:147)
                      at com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton.<init>(ProgressButton.java:116)
                      at com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton.<init>(ProgressButton.java:111)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

---

Whats bothering me is that Android Studio is referring to a dimension and saying that it is not a drawable. The problem is that it should be pointing towards a dimension.

Is this a bug in the new gradle version or should I try a different library? I would just like to know what is causing this

Comment: Are you using latest dependency of this library ?

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.zandrevanheerden.progressbartest:dimen/progress_inner_size" (7f050067) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1c01 a=4 r=0x7f050067}`

Comment: @ADM Yes, I have double checked. Should I just abandon the library and try another one?

Comment: Thats not the solution . Try to run the github sample of library. If it wirks then there must be some problem with your code.

Comment: @ADM Ran the examples, same problem

Comment: Then there must be an issue in library itself . Register a issue [Here](https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton/issues) so that the developer of that library can resolve it .  In mean time you can move on with another library or you can wait for Fix .

Answer (score 0):

```
com.f2prateek.progressbutton.ProgressButton
```

Do you have this view in this package?

You can also try Clean Project and Invalidate Cache and Restart Android Studio

Comment: Yes, I have restarted Android Studio and cleared cache as suggested. It didn't work, I recreated a new basic project where I just drop the button in, no functionality at all, just a basic Activity with view and the button, still same error.